# Why is IE7 and IE8 Giving me "Access Denied" when calling jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Google CDN to call the jQuery 1.4.2 Min File into my application.  One FF, Chrome, Safari everything is working great.  But for some reason, i get a "Access Denied" error for the jquery.min.js file on line 127...?  I don't get it.  Anyone have a clue why this is acting up in this way?  I am totally clueless.
!
[<strike>Screenshot</strike>](http://gabrielfuller.com/error.png)

Code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

.

```
case 1:
methodName = "SavePropertyInformation";
var HasFoundProperty, PropertyType, NumberOfUnits,
PropertyAddress, PropertyCity, PropertyState,
PropertyZipCode, PropertyCounty;

HasFoundProperty = $("#foundProperty input[type='radio']:checked").val();
PropertyType = $('#<%= this.fvApp.FindControl("ddlPropertyType").ClientID %>').val();
NumberOfUnits = $('#<%= this.fvApp.FindControl("ddlNumberOfUnits").ClientID %>').val();
PropertyAddress = $('#<%= this.fvApp.FindControl("txtPropertyAddress").ClientID %>').val();
PropertyCity = $('#<%= this.fvApp.FindControl("txtPropertyCity").ClientID %>').val();
PropertyState = $('#<%= this.fvApp.FindControl("ddlPropertyState").ClientID %>').val();
PropertyZipCode = $('#<%= this.fvApp.FindControl("txtPropertyZipCode").ClientID %>').val();
GetCountyFromZipCode(PropertyZipCode);
PropertyCounty = GetCounty();
data = "{WebAccessID:'" + WebAccessID + "', HasFoundProperty:'" + HasFoundProperty + "', PropertyType:'" + PropertyType + "', NumberOfUnits: '"
    + NumberOfUnits + "', PropertyAddress: '" + PropertyAddress + "', PropertyCity:'" + PropertyCity
    + "', PropertyState:'" + PropertyState + "', PropertyZipCode:'" + PropertyZipCode + "',PropertyCounty:'"
    + PropertyCounty + "' }";
doAjaxReq(methodName, data, showSavingDialog);
break;
```

Comment: When you load the jQuery file from your disk where the application resides, do you also get that message with the same browser?

Comment: I just set it up to pull the jQuery file locally and it worked fine.  Should I try to use the Google CDN for FF, Chrome, and Safari and just use the local file for IE6-8, or should I just go local for all browsers?

Comment: Actually, it worked locally but then did not work live on the site.  On the site it is still saying "Access Denied" even if calling the jQuery file from the same domain/subdomain combination... any thoughts?

Comment: I have the same problem, but my page is https, Ie8 says its insecure content so is never loaded (from cdn or from the same domain :( ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making a call to a sub domain is seen as a different domain because of the [Same Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Make sure that you are setting [document.domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.domain) to avoid access denied with the Same Origin policy.

To get the document.domain in sync you need to set it in two places. Add a script tag that set the domain, and you need to have an iframe on the page that sets the same thing on the other domain.

The page that the Ajax call is made from "www.example.com" and is calling "ajax.example.com":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.domain = "example.com";
</script>
<iframe src="http://ajax.example.com/domainCode.html"></iframe>
```

The "domainCode.html" would just contain the script tag

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.domain = "example.com";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

With that in place you should be able to talk between your sub domains.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like that on a website that doesn't belong to us? (the website loads my JS file) Could that lead to some breaking changes?

Comment: Same Origin Policy prevents you from touching other domains.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure IE doesn't have any proxy settings, auto config script, or anything like that in preferences.  I see nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem stems from a certain security feature in Internet Explorer where you are not allowed to load code from a remote server unless its considered "trusted" by the browser.  From what I read, there are instances where the browser does not complain about this, and then there are other situations where it won't allow it.  Not sure what the specific trigger is in your instance, but I would bet that's the root of your problem here.

If I were you, I would just load the jQuery locally until you have performance issues that prompt you to do otherwise.  Name the file jquery-latest.js, and then as new versions of JQ appear, test them locally first, and then replace the file when you're confident it works.  OR, keep the version-named file and upgrade each page piecemeal, whichever's easier for your application use.

Source: http://geekswithblogs.net/TimH/archive/2006/05/17/78673.aspx

Comment: It worked locally on my test environment but not on the live site.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Are you sitting behind a firewall? It could be blocking you from connecting and downloading the jquery.js.

Comment: Nope.  No firewall issue. It works fine in FF, Chrome and Safari - it is an IE issue.