# Ajax request "Access is denied" in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I use ajax request in order to check response of websites as follow,

```
$.ajax ({
    url: 'https://www.example.com',
    cache: false,
    success : function() {
        alert(new Date() - start)               
    }, 
})
```

It works on my local pc in all browsers. When I put it on the server, it works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE8.

I get the error: `"Access is denied" jquery.min.js`

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Not sure exactly what URL you're trying to get, but 1. look at CORS. Also, if you're an https site making references to a non https site (though I see your example URL has https) it's technically insecure. I've found browsers are inconsistent with how they deal with it but just a comment

Comment: This code is on the same domain as the URL you are trying to request, right?  You may be violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: @Raeki: CORS don't work 100% in IE8: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

Comment: same origin policy doesn't create problem for chrome and firefox??

Comment: @user1874941:  It does.  That may not be the issue then.  Just a theory.

Comment: Have you read this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470859/why-is-ie7-and-ie8-giving-me-access-denied-when-calling-jquery

Comment: If it's a "same origin policy" problem then the error message will be other and not `Access is denied`

Comment: Are you sure it's this line that's giving you an "access is denied" error?  The error could be elsewhere.

Comment: yes I get access is denied jquery.min.js line 127

Comment: @user1874941: That doesn't mean it's this line.  Are you trying to edit any input fields using jQuery?

Comment: I add the response time to text area inside ajax. In addition I use https websites for response. can it be related with certificates?

Comment: @user1874941: Possibly.  Is the page running on HTTPS also?

Comment: no page is running on http.

Comment: @user1874941: That's your issue!  HTTP is not the same as HTTPS.  Not sure why Chrome and Firefox aren't complaining.

Comment: I am gonna try to call http websites in order to be sure whether this is the reason.

Comment: yes it works for http pages :) so what should I do now?

Comment: AJAXing a HTTPS page from an HTTP page counts as a "cross domain" request, and browsers don't allow this.  You need to use CORS (which doesn't work 100% in IE8) or JSONP.

Comment: it is interesting that except IE allows that. I will search about your advises. thank you very much.

Comment: @user1874941: Yeah, I'm not sure why it works in other browsers, it shouldn't.  One solution would be to have the page be HTTPS also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For my case the problem is resulted because of compatibility mode. I am in intranet and internet explorer is running with compatibility mode. 
I added following tag and this solved all my problems. It forces IE to not use compatibility mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >
```

Comment: Was trying to get ie10 to use CORS and it was failing with ```error access is denied``` error and it was because i had a meta tag in the head that was telling the browser to run in ie9 compatible mode

Answer (score 6):

**--- JAN 2014 ---**
IE8 and IE9 use a different method (XDomainRequest) to communicate with cross domains.
You should consider using this if they are using jQuery:

https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

Make sure to use the same protocol as the originating call, i.e. HTTP or HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting "epascarello" from an other very similar question :

Making a call to a sub domain is seen as a different domain because of the Same Origin policy. Make sure that you are setting document.domain to avoid access denied with the Same Origin policy.

To get the document.domain in sync you need to set it in two places. Add a script tag that set the domain, and you need to have an iframe on the page that sets the same thing on the other domain.

The page that the Ajax call is made from "www.example.com" and is calling "ajax.example.com":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.domain = "example.com";
</script>
<iframe src="http://ajax.example.com/domainCode.html"></iframe>
```

The "domainCode.html" would just contain the script tag

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.domain = "example.com";
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

With that in place you should be able to talk between your sub domains.

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 1):

Note -- Note
do not use "http://www.domain.xxx" for URL in ajax.
only use path(directory) and page name without address.

**false state:**

```
var AJAXobj = createAjax();
AJAXobj.onreadystatechange = handlesAJAXcheck;
AJAXobj.open('POST', 'http://www.example.com/dir/getSecurityCode.php', true);
AJAXobj.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
AJAXobj.send(pack);
```

**true state:**

```
var AJAXobj = createAjax();
AJAXobj.onreadystatechange = handlesAJAXcheck;
AJAXobj.open('POST', 'dir/getSecurityCode.php', true);   // <<--- note
AJAXobj.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
AJAXobj.send(pack);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in IE8. What solved it for me was changing my ajax request to use the same protocol as the original page request.  In my case the original page was requested over https and the ajax request was using http.  Switching them both to use https fixed the problem.