# $.ajax get request method throws "access is denied" error message in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this following ajax request which works fine in Chrome,Firefox and also in IE10+ but not working in IE9 and lower versions.

This is the code:

```
function grab(url) {
        var result;
         $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        timeout: 1000, // feel free to mod this 
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        processData : false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
           console.log("success");
            result = data;
        },
        error: function (x, t, m) {
            console.log("failure");
            if (t === 'timeout') {
            result = { status: 500, message:"Timeout error"};
            } else {
            result = x.responseText;
            }
        }
        });
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Your dataType is invalid, `JSON` is not a valid value (but `json` is).

Comment: Why use a syncronous `$.ajax` call?

Comment: Is the URL is different origin? Same Origin Policy

Comment: "but not working in IE9 and lower versions." -- I'm not sure which jQuery version you're using, but note that jQuery 2 and newer does not support IE8 and lower.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843083/ajax-request-access-is-denied-in-ie?rq=1

Comment: I am using  jQuery v1.10.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to use CORS, which isn't fully supported in IE until version 10:

http://caniuse.com/cors

If you need to support IE8-9, you will need to use the `XDomainRequest` object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This library might smooth out the browser vagaries for you: https://github.com/dkastner/jquery.iecors

Comment: Thanks for replying but can you tell anyother better way to acheive this. I need to get it done as soon as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll need to create a fork for IE8-9, please see the link above.

Comment: Still cannot able to get the result in my IE8-IE9. The link was not helping me but I am very much thankful to you for your support.